# Firebase - Get all Children and add to ListView

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

I have 4 fragments in an activity, the Database Fragment, currently holds the ListView that will query Firebase to get the child from a parent node, "Asset". Also, the ListView have a custom adapter that has enables it to have a title and subtitle.

This is the database structure

[image]

This is the Main Activity:

```
private var toolbar: ActionBar? = null

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    toolbar = supportActionBar

    toolbar?.title = resources.getString(R.string.navigation_database)
    loadFragment(DatabaseFragment())

    setNavigation()
}
private fun setNavigation(){
    val bottomNavigationView = findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottomNavigation)
    bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener { item ->

        var fragment: Fragment

        when (item.itemId) {
            R.id.navigation_database -> {
                toolbar?.title = resources.getString(R.string.navigation_database)
                fragment = DatabaseFragment()
                loadFragment(fragment)
            }
            R.id.navigation_track -> {
                toolbar?.title = resources.getString(R.string.navigation_tracking)
                fragment = TrackingFragment()
                loadFragment(fragment)
            }
            R.id.navigation_activities -> {
                toolbar?.title = resources.getString(R.string.navigation_activities)
                fragment = ActivitiesFragment()
                loadFragment(fragment)
            }
            R.id.navigation_references -> {
                toolbar?.title = resources.getString(R.string.navigation_references)
                fragment = ReferencesFragment()
                loadFragment(fragment)
            }
        }
        true
    }
}
private fun loadFragment(fragment: Fragment){
    val fragmentTransaction = supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction()
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.childLayout, fragment)
    fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null)
    fragmentTransaction.commit()
}
```

This is the Database Fragment:

```
override fun onCreateView(inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?, savedInstanceState: Bundle?): View? {
    val rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_database, container, false)

    val titleList = ArrayList<String>()
    val subtitleList = ArrayList<String>()

    val databaseReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Assets")
    databaseReference.addValueEventListener(object : ValueEventListener{
        override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {
        }

        override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
            for(childSnapshot: DataSnapshot in dataSnapshot.children){
                titleList.add(childSnapshot.key.toString())
                subtitleList.add("subtitle")
            }
        }

    })

    val listView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.databaseListView) as ListView
    val adapter = DatabaseListAdapter(activity as MainActivity, titleList, subtitleList)
    listView.adapter = adapter

    return rootView
}
```

This is the Custom Adapter:

```
public Context context;
public ArrayList<String> titleList;
public ArrayList<String> subtitleList;

public DatabaseListAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<String> titleList, ArrayList<String> subtitleList){
    this.context = context;
    this.titleList = titleList;
    this.subtitleList = subtitleList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return titleList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return titleList.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View rootView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.layout_listview_database, parent, false);

    TextView titleView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.titleView);
    TextView subtitleView = rootView.findViewById(R.id.subtitleView);

    titleView.setText(titleList.get(position));
    subtitleView.setText(subtitleList.get(position));

    return rootView;
}
```

Firebase Database Rules:

```
{
"rules": {
".read": true,
".write": true
   }
}
```

Comment: please mention your problem statement.!

Comment: I can't currently edit the post, but the listView doesn't show any items

Comment: have a look at my answer tell me one thing more       subtitleList.add("subtitle") why you are adding this static data "subtitle ".?

Comment: well, I am currently focusing on getting the child key that will be displayed as the title

Comment: run below code and check. are you getting data or not.? and post your read write rules for firebase database

Comment: nope doesn't work, the firebase rules are set to test mode.

Comment: kindly post rules

Comment: may I ask how??

Comment: simply update adapter after adding data into list. after for each loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot)`, after you add all the stuff to your lists, you need to call `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`.

You can either keep a global `var` reference to the adapter, or find the recycler view by ID and get its adapter.

You probably also want to clear the lists before adding stuff to them.